# Database query sql

Tags: sql

Company would like to find out if there is any correlation between different months of a year
and demerit codes so you have been assigned to generate a report that shows for ALL the
demerits, the code, description, total number of offences committed for the demerit code
so far in any month (of any year) and then the total of offences committed for the demerit
code in each month (of any year). The column headings in your output should be renamed
as Demerit Code, Demerit Description, Total Offences (All Months), and then the first three
letters of each month (with the first letter in uppercase). The output must be sorted by
Total Offences (All Months) column in descending format and where there is more than
one demerit code with the same total, sort them by demerit code in ascending format. Your
output must have the form shown below. Your output can clearly be different from the
following output.

```
select d.dem_code as "Demerit Code", d.dem_description as "Demerit Description", count(o.off_no) as " Total Offences (All Months)", 
select off_datetime from offence where to_char(off_datetime, 'Mon') == 'Jan'
from demerit d join offence o
on d.dem_code = o.dem_code
group by d.dem_code, dem_description
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my query? what would be the solution for this, I've attached a copy of how output should be 
(NOTE offence and demerit are different tables
[y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGIMb.png)

[image]

Comment: `Your output must have the form shown below` - I can't see any example of output in your question.

Comment: Hi, you have to click "enter image description" for that, it's right under the last line of my question

Comment: pulled in image, typo edits

Answer (score -1):

```
                select 
            [Demerit Code],[Demerit Description],[Total Offences (All Months)],
            isnull(Jan,0) [Jan],isnull(Feb,0) [Feb],isnull(Mar,0) [Mar],isnull(Apr,0) [Apr],isnull(May,0) [May],
            isnull(Jun,0) [Jun],isnull(Jul,0) [Jul],isnull(Aug,0) [Aug],isnull(Sep,0) [Sep],isnull(Oct,0) [Oct],
            isnull(Nov,0) [Nov],isnull(Dec,0) [Dec]
            from (
            select d.dem_code as 'Demerit Code', 
            d.dem_description as 'Demerit Description',
            o.off_no,
            isnull(sum(o.off_no) OVER() ,0)'Total Offences (All Months)',
            FORMAT(o.off_datetime, 'MMM', 'en-US') as 'DateExp'
            from demerit d 
            inner join offence o
            on d.dem_code = o.dem_code
            group by d.dem_code,d.dem_description,FORMAT(o.off_datetime, 'MMM', 'en-US'),o.off_no
            ) as demerits
            pivot (
            sum(demerits.off_no) 
                FOR DateExp IN (
                    [Jan], 
                    [Feb], 
                    [Mar], 
                    [Apr], 
                    [May], 
                    [Jun], 
                    [Jul],
                    [Aug], 
                    [Sep], 
                    [Oct], 
                    [Nov], 
                    [Dec])
             ) as pivotdemerits
```